# Pandas: Comparing cell of a dataframe to content of different column & copying neighboring data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I want to iterate over the column of dataframe A and for each cell, check if its content matches any cell of a column in dataframe B. If it does, I want to copy the content of another column of that same row in dataframe B to a new column in the row of the matching cell in dataframe A.

Example:

**dataframe_a**

**name  | age**
Brad  |  36
Anita |  54
Brad |  23
Mary  |  34

**dataframe_b**

**first_name | gender**
Amy | f
Anita | f
Ben | m
Bella | f
Ben | m
Brad | m
Florian | m
Mary | f
...

**Goal: dataframe_a**

**name  | age | gender**
Brad  |  36 | m
Anita |  54 | f
Mary  |  34 | f

So far, this is what I have

```
if (dataframe_a['name'].iteritems() == dataframe_b['first_name]:
    dataframe_b['gender'] = dataframe_a['gender']
```

However, I'm getting "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().". I'm guessing I have to put a loop here, but that's super slow and I'm pretty sure there must be a faster way?

Comment: Why do you think you have to use a loop? Have you tried looking up that error message online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'first_name':'name'}))
```

output:

```
    name  age gender
0   Brad   36      m
1  Anita   54      f
2   Mary   34      f
```

You can also do this with a dictionary:

```
gender_map = dataframe_b.set_index('first_name').to_dict()['gender']  
dataframe_a['gender'] = dataframe_a.set_index('name').index.map(gender_map)
```

gender_map:

```
{'Amy': 'f',
 'Anita': 'f',
 'Ben': 'm',
 'Bella': 'f',
 'Brad': 'm',
 'Florian': 'm',
 'Mary': 'f'}
```

```
    name  age gender
0   Brad   36      m
1  Anita   54      f
2   Mary   34      f
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This doesn't work though, since df2 is a very large dataframe with all kinds of names and df2 has a small list of names, and they may come up a couple of times, so 'name' is not unique.

Comment: @laryl i updated with another approach that may help